Want some example code for Android native app/service that utilize MediaCodec MediaMuxer in C++(native) layer
I've found that there are MediaCodec class, MediaMuxer class and MediaRecorder class in Android java class APIs.
But also I know of MediaCodec, MediaMuxer and MediaRecorder classes exist in C++ layer also.
I can find code examples only for Java layer. But what I need is for C++ layer(native layer) code examples.
Can you point me some simple code examples for those C++ layer MediaCodec, MediaMuxer and/or MediaRecorder?
Thank you very much!
